# Bold textStyle attribute of textview in xml is not working after applying custom fonts in app Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, custom-font, calligraphy

### Bold textStyle attribute of textview in xml is not working after applying custom fonts in app

I have completed developement of an android app. Now I have to **change font family for whole app**. I have used **baskerville-old-face.ttf fonts** and used **Calligraphy library** to apply these fonts into my app.
Following is dependency I have used:

```
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
```

Following is the code to initilize Calligraphy library:

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder().setDefaultFontPath("fonts/baskerville.ttf").setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath).build());
```

And following is the code I have used in each Avtivity to use custom fonts:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

It is working fine and all fonts are changed **but there is only one problem that text style (bold) is not working with xml attribute.** I don't want to change each textview attribute programmatically (Using JAVA code) because there are more than 100 text views in my whole app.

I am not getting what I am doing wrong or what I am missing. Please help !

Your help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the best answer but I was seen same problem. you can use the baskervilleBold.ttf font in your code instead of baskerville.ttf if there is exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But if I use baskerville-bold, whole texts (including normal fonts) are changed to bold.. :(